# jquery AJAX post data is not passed to server on chrome and firefox (Spring MVC - requestmapping)

Tags: ajax, spring, google-chrome, post, https

I'm trying to send data using http post method by jquery ajax to the server.

The code of client-side javascript is here. (jquery version is v1.7.1)

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  async : false,
  url : "/my/context/and/path.html",
  data : "key1=value1&key2=value2",
  dataType : "json",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
  cache : false,
  crossDomain: true,
  success : function(data) {
    alert("success");
  },
  error : function(xhr, textStatus) {
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

And the server-side code is here.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my/context/and/path.html")
    public void createSomeData(
            MyVo myVo,
            HttpSession session,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

            logger.debug("user id -vo : " + myVo.getUserId());
            logger.debug("user id -request : " + request.getParameter("userId"));
}
```

It works fine when I'm using Mac with any browsers. (logger writes appropriate user id).
Even if I use Windows 7, it works fine on IE8.

However the problem is that the request parameter is not passed when I use
chrome or firefox on Windows7.

Furthermore, I have to environment in which same web application is deployed.
One is using https and the other is using http for web server.

The problem i've mentioned earlier only occurred on the web server which uses https(SSL).

Could anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could not find the exact solution but it may be related to some request parameters.

After I've removed some unnecessary parameters, it works fine.

It is still strange problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the chrome u can use firebug lite a debugging tool so that u can see exactly what is happening when request is made on chrome .

http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/

Comment: Yes. I've tried to debugging using firebug.
It says an exception occurred in 
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
line of jquery-lastest.js.

For this reason, request has no parameters event though the server method has been called.

Comment: @HosangJeon  may be the version of jquery creating problem on chrome or in the method call some wrong value being passed

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with Firefox 24. jQuery v1.7.2 . It works fine.

Comment: The cause of the problem seems to be the length of request body(5KB).
I've tested after remove lots of input tags then it works fine even in chrome and firefox.
Is there any limitation of post body size in web browser?